# What is this cactus with smooth round spineless stems?

Tags: identification, cactus

Does anyone know the name of this plant? I have been searching everywhere for its name, but failed terribly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's [Euphorbia leucodendron](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/euphorbia-leucodendron-80188.html), the "Pencil Cactus".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am allowed only (allowed by myself) a certain amount of time to ID. Arghhh! 
The plant that is a succulent and produces 'babies' like this is Kalanchoe.  I'm going for Kalanchoe delagoensis.  This one is tough!  Hey, someone will love proving me wrong to get this right!  I am dying to know this one...